# Как сделать так , чтобы программа считала из текстового файла данные?

Tags: c++

Программа должна сравнить цены каждого клиента который покупает дом. Объясняю что тут написано, 1)проценты 2) Сумма вложения 3) Не выплаченная сумма 4) Тип строения 5) Вся сумма. Затем после того как программа прочитала , что написано в данном файле она должна вывести Тип строения у которого цена самая большая, я не пойму как программа должна прочитать последние цифры в конце каждой строки и сравнить их друг с другом

4.5,60000,25000,Квартира,85000

10.2,147804,15267,Бизнес-центр,163052

8.9,94000,25000,Частный дом,119000

10.5,85000,60000,Магазин,145000

5.5,62500,36050,Дом,98550

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <WINDOWS.h>
using namespace std;

struct bydova
{
    struct pokypatel
    {
        float procenti;
        float symmavlogenia;
        float neviplatsymma;

    }object;
    char typestroenia[100];
    int cena;
    char firma[100];
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    int max = 0; //тип дома с макс стоимостью 
    ifstream phile("inform.txt");
    if (!phile.is_open()) 
    {
        cerr << "Ошибка открытия файла!";
        return 0;
    }
    while (phile.getline(bydovi, 256))
    {
        char* token = strtok(bydovi, ",");
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну для начала вам нужно создать буффер куда будете записывать прочитанную из файла строчку. У вас он называется по идее `bydovi`, но переменная с таким названием у вас нигде не определена.

Например так:

```
char buffer[256];
```

И в условии цикла:

```
while(phile.getline(buffer, 256))
```

Так же нужно создать экземпляр структуры `bydova` куда мы будем записывать информацию из файла.

В самом цикле, как вы начали уже делать, нужно разбивать строку `buffer` по разделителю `,`.

После выполнения функции `strtok` в `token` будут хранится данные, которые вам нужно сконвертировать в правильный тип данных и записать это в созданную ранее структуру.

Для этого вам потребуется две функции:

1. `atof` - функция конвертирует строку в вещественное число `float`.

   Тут важно отметить, что вы пишите `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");`, по этому разделителем целой части от дробной является запятая. После выполнения этой функции например из `"4.5"` вы будете получать `4`, а не `4.5`.

   Самый простой способ решить эту проблему написать вместо `LC_ALL` `LC_CTYPE`
2. `atoi` - конвертирует строку в целочисленный тип данных `int`

Так же вам нужна функция `strcpy(строка1, строка2)`, которая копирует `строка2` в `строка1`, она потребуется для того, чтобы скопировать тип строения в структуру `bydova`

Вот пример кода:

```
char buffer[256];
bydova data;
while (phile.getline(buffer, 256))
{
    char* token = strtok(buffer, ",");
    data.object.procenti = atof(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    data.object.symmavlogenia = atof(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    data.object.neviplatsymma = atof(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(data.typestroenia, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    data.cena = atoi(token);
    //После строк выше в data будет записаны данные из 1 строчки
    //тут вы можете работать с ним, как вам нужно
}
```

Comment: Вопрос такой, вы написали: "//После строк выше в data будет записаны данные из 1 строчки" , а с остальными строками я не смогу работать ?

Comment: @Young Конечно можете, тогда вам нужно создать массив и туда записывать все данные. Просто если вам нужно искать например, что-то максимальное, то можно и без массива это делать.

Comment: вообще не могу понять как мне теперь найти самую максимальную цену дома, можете как-то подсказать?

Comment: @Young вообще ваш вопрос был не в этом, но я уверен если немного погуглить вы сможете найти информацию как это сделать :)

Comment: Лучше считать весь файл целиком, а не построчно. В крайнем случае блоками по 1 мегабайту.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков нет, в данной задаче лучше считать построчно.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас стоит метка `C++`, то почему бы не воспользоваться возможностями языка C++?

Я бы переписал ваш код так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

struct client_s
{
    double percent = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    long long deposit = -1;
    long long debt = -1;
    std::string building_type;
    long long total_sum = -1;
};

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    //Создаём копию глобальной локали, но фасеты из категории std::locale::numeric
    //берём из "C"-локали. Теперь десятичный разделитель - точка.
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), "C", std::locale::numeric);
    std::ifstream file("inform.txt");
    file.imbue(loc);

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Cant open file!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    client_s best_client;
    const char delim = ',';
    const auto ignore_delim = std::ifstream::traits_type::to_int_type(delim);
    const auto ignore_size  = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        client_s client;

        file >> client.percent; file.ignore(ignore_size, ignore_delim);

        file >> client.deposit; file.ignore(ignore_size, ignore_delim);
        file >> client.debt;    file.ignore(ignore_size, ignore_delim);

        std::getline(file, client.building_type, delim);

        file >> client.total_sum;

        if (file.fail())
            break;

        std::cout << 
            client.percent       << " " << 
            client.deposit       << " " << 
            client.debt          << " " << 
            client.building_type << " " << 
            client.total_sum     << std::endl;

        if (client.total_sum > best_client.total_sum)
            best_client = client;
    }
    file.close();

    std::cout << "Best client: " <<
            best_client.percent       << " " << 
            best_client.deposit       << " " << 
            best_client.debt          << " " << 
            best_client.building_type << " " << 
            best_client.total_sum     << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```